# ElasticSearch JVM option file location?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jvm

I have Elastic Search v7.5.1 cluster running on windows servers as a windows service (services.msc).

We want to add a configuration in the ES JVM option. I tried in `config\jvm.options` and restarted the node. The node came up, got added to the cluster but the property was not picked up (checked from `http://<node_server>/_nodes/jvm?pretty`).

[image]

Upon search, I found multiple `jvm.options` file in other locations on the server.

Is there a possibility of `jvm.options` file being picked from a non-default location? If yes, then how to connect breadcrumbs and reach the "used" file location?

I come from .Net background :) and less aware of the java ecosystem. Apols in advance. :) :)

Comment: Hi, have you had the chance to take a look at the documentation ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/advanced-configuration.html#set-jvm-options

Comment: Thanks. I have read this and was trying option #1 of this. ES_JAVA_OPTS is only for dev. Not recommended for prod.

Answer (score 0):

For window service you can refer this
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/zip-windows.html#windows-service
You can specify below setting
ES_PATH_CONF

Configuration file directory (which needs to include elasticsearch.yml, jvm.options, and log4j2.properties files), defaults to %ES_HOME%\config.

Comment: Thanks, Tulsi. The environment variable points to the same location where I'm changing it. Still, it's not picked up.